# Can't open image file after upload to s3 bucket using ngx-uploader module

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am using ngx-uploader module to upload image to s3 using a presigned url on Angular2+.

Here is my code client-side

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { UploadOutput, UploadInput, UploadFile, humanizeBytes, UploaderOptions, UploadProgress } from 'ngx-uploader';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-dialog',
  templateUrl: './upload-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-dialog.component.scss'],
})
export class UploadDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  options: UploaderOptions;
 
  uploadInput: EventEmitter<UploadInput>;
  fileName: string;
  constructor(
              public dialogRef:         MatDialogRef<UploadDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
               
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  uploadFichier(output: UploadOutput): void {
    if (output.type === 'addedToQueue'  && typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
      this.currentFile = output.file;
      this.fileName = output.file.name;
    }
    // si l'upload est fini
    if (output.type === 'done') {

     // when upload done
    }
  }

  saveFile() {
  
      const respo = response.json();
      let event: UploadInput;
        console.log(this.currentFile)
        event = {
          type: 'uploadFile',
          file: this.currentFile,
          url: 'url here',
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {'Content-Type': this.currentFile.type}
        };
      
      this.uploadInput.emit(event);
      /** */
    
  }

  cancel() {
    const cancelEvent: UploadInput = {
      type: 'cancelAll'
    };
    this.uploadInput.emit(cancelEvent);
    
  }

}
```

```html
  <input id="add-scolaire"  type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
                mat-icon-button 
                ngFileSelect 
                [options]="options" 
                (uploadOutput)="uploadFichier($event)" 
                [uploadInput]="uploadInput">
```

When  I try to download and open image after uploading, I got this message : "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2d 0x2d)".
Maybe the problem is that, ngx-uploader upload file using form-data method by adding additional information on the file header.

Answer (score 1):

How do you process the file on the server side?

ngx-uploader works with multipart/form-data for the upload.

There is an example server in the repo [Demo Server](https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader/blob/master/src/api/index.ts).

Comment: From server side, I use aws-sdk to generate a presigned url, then i use this url to upload directly the image to s3 from client-side. I have just created a gist to illustrate it: https://gist.github.com/raslasarslas/f2df70b3a8330b71a8c1423ae3c3063d

Comment: could you have a look at this issue? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/558#issuecomment-89385027

The sdk needs a stream not multipart/form-data. As a work around, save the file onto your server and then stream it to S3.

Comment: I add your gist to the milestones for ngx-uploader. See: 
[Issue 392](https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader/issues/392)